# recording and editing audio with react-native

Tags: react-native

I am starting a react-native ios app and needs to have record and edit audio features. Is there any react-native packages out there that I can install that already has these features or do I need to create my own?

Answer (score 2):

You can try these npm packages

[react-native-audio-player-recorder](https://github.com/Shinetechchina/react-native-audio-player-recorder)

[react-native-audio](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio)